# How to remove from scope when not in use in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've setup a controller to tick every few seconds, which in turn makes a restful call to a backend api. Everything is working as expected, except when I navigate to another section (handled by a separate controller), the tick continues to fire.

Is it possible to remove the controller from scope entirely?

Here's a paste of my current controller:

```
myApp.controller('SupervisorController', function($scope, supervisord, $timeout) {

    $scope.supervisord = supervisord;

    (function tick() {
        $scope.supervisord.fetch();
        $timeout(tick, 2500);
    })();
});
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know as well how you implemented tick with $watch. Would it be possible to add it to your question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) it mentions that

> Just before a scope is destroyed a $destroy event is broadcasted on
>   this scope. Application code can register a $destroy event handler
>   that will give it chance to perform any necessary cleanup.

This seems like exactly what you want.

Comment: You were right, this is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up moving my tick into a $watch, and added a $destroy event which just deletes my service. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Mark Pitman: I have an issue similar to yours (i.e. polling a REST API). You wrote _I ended up moving my tick into a $watch_. Do you have some code sample somewhere that explains you solution ?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use `var myInterval = setInterval(tick, 2500);` to get it going and later `clearInterval(myInterval);` to stop it again (or the analogous [$timeout.cancel(myInterval)](http://jsfiddle.net/gxlcl/HfYPE/)). For that you need access to `myInterval` in both controllers, so you might consider wrapping it in a [Angular service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services).

Comment: I could do the same with the current approach, but that's going to require me to clear that interval in a separate controller right?

Comment: I'm curious to know if there's a way that I could 'watch' the controller, and if the user navigates to a different section of the UI, then unload/remove/destroy the controller completely?

Comment: If you're using [routes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route), you probably could clear the timer in the $routeChangeSuccess callback.